# Cordova/Phonegap app breaking only in WP8

Tags: internet-explorer, cordova, windows-phone-8

I'm creating a PhoneGap app that works fine when initially installed, but then gives an error when loaded for a second time. The error is "An unknown error has occurred. Error 80020101." 
The error occurs when attempting to call the nativeReady.

I understand this error is commonly encountered in IE (this only happens in WP8, not in any other mobile OS), and means that there was a syntax error. So I need to know what's causing this. I've tried loading the scripts in markup and dynamically, neither of which has worked.

Console logs for first startup:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
Updating IsolatedStorage for APP:DeviceID :: ea767f9b-c9d2-441d-9d41-9e7f92ddbde0
ScriptNotify :: Installed console!
About to load cordova
Detected Cordova
CordovaBrowser_LoadCompleted
About to load cordova
Detected Cordova
```

Logs for second startup:

```
ScriptNotify :: Installed console!
CordovaBrowser_LoadCompleted
About to load cordova
A first chance exception of type 'System.SystemException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.Interop.ni.dll
Error calling js to fire nativeReady event. Did you include cordova.js in your html script tag?
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem and have no idea what is causing the problem - did you get any further?

Comment: Hi user2564511, how you solved this?

Comment: I honestly can't remember. Probably something stupid.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you start developing with phonegap in new platform or new computer, you should re-install your plugins. I suggest remove your plugins and re-install them.

For example:

Remove plugins

```
phonegap local plugin remove org.apache.cordova.console
phonegap local plugin remove org.apache.cordova.device
phonegap local plugin remove org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
```

Add plugins

```
phonegap local plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
phonegap local plugin add org.apache.cordova.console
phonegap local plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
```

After that control that, you included necessary cordova javascript files.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../cordova_plugins.js"></script>
```